# Ошибка с базой данных, нет такой таблицы?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, unity3d

Есть база данных в которую нужно записать значения из полей "регистрация в игре" при попытке записи выдает ошибку `Unable to open Assets/youtube.bytes.db: Check external application preferences`.

При проверке через `try catch` пишет:

> Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite error no such table: Users
>   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Prepare (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection
>   cnn, System.String strSql, Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement previous,
>   UInt32 timeoutMS, System.String& strRemain)
>   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.BuildNextCommand ()
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

как это исправить и что это такое? приложение Desktop

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class db_controller : MonoBehaviour {

public SqliteConnection con_db;
public SqliteCommand cmd_db;
public SqliteDataReader rdr;

public string path;
public Text text;

string id;
string log;
string pass;

public InputField idfield;
public InputField login;
public InputField password;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void Connection()
{           
    path = Application.dataPath + "/youtube.bytes";
    con_db = new SqliteConnection ("URI=file:" + path);
    con_db.Open ();

}
public void SetDB(){
Connection();
id=idfield.text.ToString();
    log=login.text.ToString();
    pass=password.text.ToString();

    cmd_db=new SqliteCommand("INSERT INTO Users(id,login,pass) VALUES('"+id+"','"+log+"','"+pass+"')", con_db);
    cmd_db.ExecuteNonQuery ();
    Disconnect();
}
private void Disconnect(){
    con_db.Close ();
}


}
```

[image: бд]

Comment: Таблица, думаю, понятно, а база какая?

Comment: Проблема может быть не с таблицей, а с подключением бд. Убедись что выполнил эти шаги: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html

Comment: Вопрос не отвечен зеленой галкой.. и к тому.. же ответ неочень понятен. На какое расширение поменяли не указано... может вопрос просто закрыть?

Answer (score 1):

проблема решена, исправлено расширение бд